# Позволит ли Apple опубликовать приложение в AppStore если оно будет запускать Web приложения?

Tags: ios, html5, webview, appstore

Позволит ли Apple опубликовать приложение в AppStore если оно будет запускать через WebView игры на HTML5 или других Web технологиях?

Answer (score 1):

Все зависит от Вашей игры. В принципе Apple не запрещает это, но по разным причинам Apple может и не пустить приложение в AppStore. Вот [тут](http://www.joshmorony.com/5-reasons-apple-might-reject-your-html5-mobile-app/) можете почитать про самые популярные причины.